# Express startup exceptions aren't caught

Tags: node.js, express, server

I'm trying to do a very simple thing: initialize an Express server. It works, but error handling doesn't. No matter what I try, exceptions go unhandled and the application crashes.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I supply an incorrect port number to `app.listen` to cause an exception. If I change it to a valid one, the server starts all right.

```
const port = -1;

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('This is an exception.');
    console.log(err);
});

try {
    app.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           process.exit();
        }
        console.log('Connected on port ' + port);
    });

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    process.exit();
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying three different methods of exception handling, but neither works. What am I missing? The app is using TypeScript.

Comment: Why are you trying to handle express initialization errors?

Comment: So it won't just vomit an exception onto the screen.

Comment: second argument to app.listen is a callback function, so you cannot wrap it inside try catch. Control will never go to catch.

Comment: What do you mean "the app crashes"?  You are logging the exception (vomiting onto the screen as you say) and then exiting the app.  YOUR code is explicitly doing that.  If you don't want it to do that, change YOUR code to do something different when it gets an error.  So, what exactly is the problem you want help with?

Comment: Of course it's MY code doing it, but the exception should be caught in some way. It doesn't matter if I log the value of `err`, the exception still gets printed regardless it's there or not.

Comment: can you post the error message, I just copied the code and works fine on my device, and please try to elaborate a bit more, it's ambiguous, you've mentioned that your code works fine for valid port number and throws an exception for invalid once. at the same time, you're saying that it is not handling the exception and crashing, of course, if you provide invalid port, it is bound to crash, and in it my case, it is also logging exception so it is handling exception as well. and it does not print regardless if there is an err.

Comment: To add more mystery, now it works for me... and I haven't touched it at all. WTF?

Comment: OK, I found the reason. `process.exit()` will exit silently if there's no exit code, but if I specify one, or set `process.exitCode` before calling it, an exception will be thrown and printed on the screen.